# Build Error while building camel maven project

Tags: maven, apache-camel

I am getting below error when building the camel example project.

Can someone help me on this?

```
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.camel:camel-example-servlet-tomcat:2.15.2 (D:\apache-camel-2.15.2\examples\camel-example-servlet-tomcat\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]   Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.7, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.7, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.7 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginManagerException: Plugin org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.7, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.7, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.7, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.7 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupExtensionsRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:874)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: General cleanup (code layout)

Comment: What version of Maven do you use? Seems like you use an too old version

Comment: Your POM.xml having issue according to stack you posted 
(D:\apache-camel-2.15.2\examples\camel-example-servlet-tomcat\pom.xml) has 1 error

Look like you are not added the proper dependencies.